# How set width of UIImageView based on it's leading and trailing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I set leading and trailing for UIImageView, I want it's width set based on these two distances. I also set it's height equal to its width. But it followed these constraints along with its default image size. I don't want default image size. What can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraints are both contradictory and insufficient. Let's take a closer look.

If you set the leading and trailing, you must not set the width; you'll end up with a contradiction, because you are setting the width *twice* in two different ways with what will certainly be (on some devices) two different values.

So:

- Just set the leading and trailing, plus the height equal to the width by using the Aspect Ratio.
- You also need to set the top or the bottom (or the vertical center), but not both, because otherwise you have given no vertical positioning info.

That takes care of the image view. But we must also give attention to *how the image view displays its image*. So *also* set the Content Mode of the image view to Aspect Fit (or Aspect Fill), plus make sure that the image view's "Clips to bounds" is set to true, and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the property **Size to Fit** in Attribute inspector, the image will respect your width constraints.  if the image is the height of the `UIImageView` or less, this will work fine.  However, if the height is larger than the width, Aspect Fit will increase the height of the `UIImageView`.

Setting **Clip to Bounds** in Attribute inspector will clip the top and the bottom of the image to fit the `UIImageView`.